# Memory managing container design issue - items require inheritance

Tags: c++, memory, c++11, unique-ptr

I'm designing a memory managing container, with performance and ease of use in mind, especially for game development projects. [Here's it in it's current state.](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVUtils/blob/master/include/SSVUtils/MemoryManager/MemoryManager.h)

I'll extract the most important parts from the source.

```
// Uptr is a typedef for std::unique_ptr

class MemoryManageable {
    bool alive{true};
    public: bool isAlive() const { return alive; }
};

template<typename T> struct Deleter {
    bool operator()(const Uptr<T>& mItem) const { return !mItem->isAlive(); } 
};  

template<typename T> class MemoryManager {
    // T is the type of items being stored and must inherit MemoryManageable
    std::vector<Uptr<T>> items; 
    std::vector<T*> toAdd; // will be added to items on the next refresh() call
    Deleter<T> deleter;

    void refresh() { 
        items.erase(std::remove_if(std::begin(items), std::end(items), deleter), std::end(items)); 
        for(const auto& i : toAdd) items.push_back(Uptr<T>(i)); toAdd.clear(); 
    }
    void clear() { items.clear(); toAdd.clear(); }

    // Del sets alive to false, so that the item will be deleted and deallocated on the next refresh() call
    void del(T& mItem) { mItem.alive = false; }

    template<typename TType, typename... TArgs> TType& create(TArgs&&... mArgs) { /* creates a new TType* (derived from T) and puts it in toAdd */ }
    template<typename... TArgs> T& create(TArgs&&... mArgs) { return create<T, TArgs...>(std::forward<TArgs>(mArgs)...); }
}
```

[You can see a real usage here.](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVEntitySystem/blob/master/src/SSVEntitySystem/Core/Manager.cpp)

The desired usage is something like this:

```
struct Entity : public MemoryManageable { 
     Manager& manager; 
     void destroy() { manager.del(*this); } 
     ... 
}

struct Mnnager { 
    MemoryManager<Entity> mm; 
    void del(Entity& mEntity) { mm.del(mEntity); }
    ... 
 }

Manager::update() {
    mm.refresh(); // entities with 'alive == false' are deallocated, and entities in 'mm.toAdd' are added to 'mm.items' 
    for(auto& entity : mm) entity->update(); // entities 'die' here, setting their 'alive' to false 
}
```

This kind of delayed insertion design with `refresh()` has some great advantages:

- It's fast
- An entity can be "killed" even if already dead
- Entities can be created from other entities as they do not get directly stored in items until `populate()` is called

However, I would love if there was no need of inheriting `MemoryManageable`, and if there was a more elegant way to delete entities.

- **Is there a way to make `MemoryManager` handle the `alive` bool internally, without having to inherit `MemoryManageable`, and, most importantly, without any performance overhead?**
- **Is there a more elegant way that could be used to delete items handled by `MemoryManager`?**

Ideally, items handled by the `MemoryManager` should know nothing about it.

---

Example usage: in gamedev, it's common that an entity gets destroyed during its update. Consider a "Enemy" entity with a int life member: `if(life <= 0) this->destroy();` - that would happen easily during an update loop, and if the entity, on destruction, is immediately removed from the Manager, it causes trouble with looping and other entities that point to the dead entity.

Comment: Yes, it's possible; the "deleter" can be a trivial lambda. The vector can store pair<unique_ptr<T>, bool>, one member being the isValid flag. But the question is, why would you want to do that? I fail to see what problem your MemoryManager is addressing, nor why it would be faster or more useful than a straight vector<unique_ptr<>>.

Comment: @DanielKO the issue lies in the `entity->update()` loop. What if an entity destroys another entity during the update? If I remove the destroyed entity immediately, the loop will fail to continue properly as its elements would be modified.

Comment: @DanielKO: your solution has a problem, I think: how is the Entity supposed to set the bool in the pair to false without knowledge of being in a pair? I mean, how can entity->destroy() set the bool to false if the Entity doesn't store a pointer to its pair?

Comment: Again, why would you want an entity in a vector to destroy another entity in the same vector, from within a loop? This seems like a convoluted operation; you want the entities to manage the vector, and not the manager, yet they somehow should not know they are doing it... It seems more natural to me to let the Manager operate on the objects; in such cases, a simple std::remove() followed by .erase() is often enough.

Comment: @DanielKO: in gamedev, it's common that an entity gets destroyed during its update. Consider a "Enemy" entity with a `int life` member: `if(life <= 0) this->destroy();` - that would happen easily during an update loop, and if the entity, on destruction, is immediately removed from the Manager, it causes trouble with looping and other entities that point to the dead entity. Also, what if 10000 entities die at the same time? It would require 10000 erase-remove idiom calls, when a remove_if is much more efficient and safe.

Comment: The update loop would do its thing, setting the enemies' health to zero, add points to the player. Then, outside the "update loop" I would perform a "remove dead enemies" operation remove(), .erase() as I said; of course I mean the whole family of remove algorithms. My point is, the restrictions you are imposing on the design are artificial, you can already accomplish the task without the restrictions. I suggest you edit your original post to include the details you just commented so people can better understand the question and maybe suggest something other than "don't".

Comment: @DanielKO I use this design with the post-update-loop cleanup in more parts of my libs. That's why I want to abstract it in `MemoryManager`, to avoid unnecessary repetition and hide the implementation details where possible. What you just explained is basically what I am doing, I just want to abstract the functionality into this container. So far it works well and the duplicated code is gone, but I really hate the fact that items managed by my container need to inherit `MemoryManageable`. I just want to find a way around that without losing performance - why do you say I am restricting myself?

Comment: If the objects share responsibility with the manager to manage themselves, it's only fair for them to inherit this behaviour. Hierarchies are meant to express those kinds of design details. I wrote games with space ships, missiles, asteroids, and didn't have the requirement to kill the same object multiple times, so that's why I'm considering it an artificial requirement. As I said, include the extra usage you comment into the original post so people can respond to it without digging through the comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The presented answers didn't satisfy me, so I decided to keep the *required inheritance* solution. As annoying it may be, it's effective (no additional runtime costs) and simple to implement/maintain.

Current implementation: [SSVUtils/MemoryManager/MemoryManager.h](https://github.com/SuperV1234/SSVUtils/blob/master/include/SSVUtils/MemoryManager/MemoryManager.h)

Answer (score 3):

First thing to say: I'm not very fond of C++11, so there *could* be some syntax error in the code I wrote, but it's the logic that matters.

If I understood your question, you just want to be able to asynchronously add and delete items from a container, without those knowing of their state. In this scenario you can use a `std::map< std::unique_ptr< Elem >, bool >` to handle the state of items: `true` = alive, `false` = dead.

#### MemoryManager class

*fields*:

- `std::vector< T * > m_toAdd`, a vector with not yet added items;
- `std::map< std::unique_ptr< T >, bool > m_items`, a map with every item managed and a `bool` flag

*methods*:

- `add()`, which adds a new item in the `m_toAdd` vector;
- `del()`, which marks an item to be removed in `m_items` using its flag;
- `refresh()`, which removes dead items and commits `m_toAdd` items ad alive in `m_items`, then clears the vector

#### Elem class

*fields*:

- `MemoryManager & m_manager`, a reference to its memory manager;

*methods*:

- `Elem()`, ctor, which calls `m_manager::add()`;
- `del()`, which calls `m_manager::del()`.

#### Creation

When an `Elem` is created, it automatically add itself to its memory manager, which adds it to its `m_toAdd` vector, then when everything is refreshed, those `Elem`s in this vector are passed in the `std::map` paired with a `true` boolean (initially marked as alive).

#### Deletion

When an `Elem` is to be deleted, it calls a `del()` method of its manager which simply marks it as dead in its `std::map`, then when everything is refreshed, every `Elem` in the manager flagged as dead is removed, and the `m_toAdd` vector is cleared.

(Also I reccomend you using `std::enable_shared_from_this` in order to better handle the ptr, but you'll have to use `std::shared_ptr`, not `std::unique_ptr`, but that could not be so bad.)

My suggestion is something like:

```
template< class T >
class MemoryManager
{
   typedef std::unique_ptr< T > unique_t;
   typedef std::map< unique_t, bool > map_t;
   typedef std::pair< unique_t, bool > pair_t;
   typedef std::vector< T * > vector_t;

public:
   void add(T * item)
   {
      m_toAdd.push_back(item);
   }

   void remove(T & item)
   {
      typename map_t::iterator it = m_items.find(item);
      if (it != m_items.end() )(* it).second = false;
   }

   void refresh()
   {
      // clear dead
      typename map_t::iterator it = m_items.begin();
      while ((it = std::find_if(it, m_items.end(), isDead)) != m_items.end())
      {
         m_items.erase(it++);
      }

      // add new
      for(T & item : m_toAdd)
      {
         m_items.insert(std::make_pair(unique_t(item), true));
      }
      m_toAdd.clear();
   }

   void clear()
   {
      m_items.clear();
      m_toAdd.clear();
   }

protected:
   bool isDead(pair_t itemPair)
   {
      // true = alive, false = dead
      return itemPair.second;
   }

private:
   map_t m_items;
   vector_t m_toAdd;
};

class Entity
{
public:
   Entity(MemoryManager< Entity > & manager)
      : m_manager(manager)
   {
      m_manager.add(this);
   }

   void die()
   {
      m_manager.remove(this);
   }

private:
   MemoryManager< Entity > & m_manager;
};
```

**NOTE**: the code is not tested and certainly broken, the important thing is the logic!

Comment: This solution seems to have a performance loss though - items in the `MemoryManager` are looped on constantly (per frame), so using a map instead of a cache-friendly vector would surely slow the iteration down

Comment: “I'm not very fond of C++11” – Indeed, your code makes that obvious. You should strive to learn it. Your code will become shorter and cleaner as a result. (To make this clear: your code isn’t *bad* by any means! – but there are a few places where C++11 makes it easier.)

Comment: @busy_wait no, because the dtor is called when the instance is removed from the heap (it's a ptr), so it will lead to a bad call to the manager (the `Elem` is no more in the map). @Konrad Rudolph, yeah, I'm working on that!

Comment: @VittorioRomeo, for that you should take a look at `boost::flat_map` http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/container/non_standard_containers.html#container.non_standard_containers.flat_xxx, or another solution, less elegant, is to have a vector of `std::pair< bool, Elem >`, or even two paired vectors, one for the booleans, the other for the instances, with a one-to-one correspondence.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I'm not entirely sure this is what you want to do but lets try this... Entity will still need destroy/isdead functions because as I understand it, you want to explicitly control its lifetime from the object itself.

```
class Entity{ 
public:
  void destroy(){ dead = true; }
  bool isDead(){ return dead; }
private:
  bool dead{false};
};


struct EntityPred{
  bool operator ()(const Entity* p){
    return p->isDead();
  }
};

template<typename T, typename T_PRED>
class MemoryManager{
  // Deletion and insertion is faster to a list than a vector 
  // since deletion of entites[0] requires v.size() - 1 copy constructions.
  // If you really worry about performance (I wouldn't until I have profiled)
  // you can use a memory pool allocator for this.
  std::list<std::unique_ptr<T> > entities;
  // Buffering up many objects that are deleted sequentially is 
  // faster in a vector, less calls to new/delete.
  // But, a pool backed list might be even faster if you're micro optimizing.
  std::vector<T*> toAdd;

public:
  void add(T* p){ toAdd.push_back(p); }

  void refresh(){
    for(auto it = entities.begin(); it != entities.end();){
      if( T_PRED(it) )
        it = entities.erase(it);
      else
        it++;
    }
    // Avoid growing the vector inside the loop since we know the size.
    entities.reserve(entities.size() + toAdd.size());
    for(auto it : toAdd){
      entities.push_back(std::unique_ptr<T>(*it));
    }
    toAdd.clear();
  }
};

MemoryManager<Entity, EntityPred> mgr;
```

The `Entity` class doesn't know about the manager and doesn't need any precautions when design it, just make sure `EntityPred` can determine if `Entity` should be deleted in some way.

Comment: It's quite similar to your solution but it doesn't require inheritance and the deletion mechanism is a bit simplified. I think that was what you wanted?

Comment: This is what I had before using inheritance - it has the same issue of making the user write boilerplate code

Comment: I think you might be out of luck, and have to choose either boiler plate or inheritance/performance loss in some way. My second answer below only requires a working move ctor and a virtual destructor.

Answer (score 0):

This question tickled my brain to come up with the a very... interesting... piece of code. Cue the applaus "And the winner of the year 2013's "(f)Ugliest Hack Award" is... " (You have been warned!)

The following code compiles and works as expected with GCC 4.7, there may be bugs and you might want to clean it up a little bit... But to the design of the Entity class, being used in a container is completely transparent. No pointers to managers, no "amideadyet" variables etc.

Basically, I'm (ab)using the destructor call order by inheriting a class from `Entity` using templates. When entity is deleted, the inherited class's destructor is called while the Entity is still valid. It notifies the manager (which the derived class has a pointer to) and steals the contents of Entity into another object which will identify as "deleted" to the manager until `refresh()` is called. The destruction of the original `Entity` continues but all expensive data members have been stolen by the move constructor and the destruction completes successfully without destroying our important data.

Enjoy :)

```
#include <memory>
#include <utility>
#include <list>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

class Entity{
public:
  Entity(const std::string& msg){ m=msg;};

  // Move constructor required
  Entity(Entity&& that){
    std::swap(m, that.m);
    c = that.c;
  }

  // Should be virtual
  virtual ~Entity(){}; 

  // Do this to release it. 
  void suicide(){  delete this; }

  // Not needed, deleted for safety
  Entity(const Entity&) = delete;
  void operator = (const Entity&) = delete;

  void print(){
    std::cout<<m<<" "<<c<<std::endl;
    c++;
  }

private:
  std::string m;
  int c{0};
};

template<typename T>
class MemoryManager;

template<typename T>
class MemoryObject{
public:
  MemoryObject(MemoryManager<T>* _mgr) : mgr(_mgr) {}
  MemoryObject(MemoryObject&& that){
    mgr = that.mgr;
  }
  MemoryObject(const MemoryObject& that){
    mgr = that.mgr;
  }
  virtual ~MemoryObject(){}
  void operator = (const MemoryObject&) = delete;

  bool isDead(){ return is_dead; }

  friend void swap(MemoryObject& a, MemoryObject& b){
    std::swap(a.mgr, b.mgr);
    std::swap(a.is_dead, b.is_dead);
  }
protected:
  bool is_dead;
  MemoryManager<T>* mgr;
};

template<typename T>
class LiveMemoryObject : public MemoryObject<T>, public T {
public:
  template<typename... ARGS>
  LiveMemoryObject(MemoryManager<T>* _mgr, const ARGS&... args) 
    : MemoryObject<T>(_mgr), T(args...)
  {}
  LiveMemoryObject(const LiveMemoryObject&) = delete;
  LiveMemoryObject(LiveMemoryObject&& other) = delete;
  virtual ~LiveMemoryObject(){
    // Called when Entity did `delete this` but before it is destroyed, 
    // The manager will move construct (swap) a DeadMemoryObject from *this
    // Effectively stealing the contents of Entity before it is destroyed.
    // So when this destructor returns, this object is pointing to a dummy Entity
    // which is destroyed inplace of the original.
    MemoryObject<T>::mgr->remove(this);
  }
  void operator = (const LiveMemoryObject&) = delete;
};

template<typename T>
class DeadMemoryObject : public MemoryObject<T>, public T {
public:
  DeadMemoryObject() = delete;
  DeadMemoryObject(const DeadMemoryObject&) = delete;
  DeadMemoryObject(LiveMemoryObject<T>&& that) 
    : MemoryObject<T>(that), T(static_cast<T&&>(that))
  {
    MemoryObject<T>::is_dead = true;
  }
  virtual ~DeadMemoryObject(){ /* May you finally R.I.P. Entity! */ }
  void operator = (const DeadMemoryObject&) = delete;
};


template<typename T>
class MemoryManager{
private:
  friend class LiveMemoryObject<T>;

  class Handle{
  public:
    template<typename... ARGS>
    explicit Handle(MemoryManager* mgr, const ARGS&... args)
    {
      auto o = new LiveMemoryObject<T>(mgr, args...);
      data = o;
      ptr = o;
    }

    ~Handle(){
      delete data;
    }

    T* operator -> (){ 
      return ptr; 
    }
    const T* operator -> () const { 
      return ptr; 
    }
  private:
    void ageData(){
      auto p = new DeadMemoryObject<T>(std::move(*dynamic_cast<LiveMemoryObject<T>*>(data)));
      data = p;
      ptr = p;
    }

    friend class MemoryManager;
    MemoryObject<T>* data; // Memory owned by handle
    T* ptr; // ease of access to T* of data.
  };

  typedef std::shared_ptr<Handle> HandlePtr;

  std::list<HandlePtr> items;
  std::list<HandlePtr> to_add;

  void remove(LiveMemoryObject<T>* p){
    for(auto it = items.begin(); it != items.end(); ++it){
      if( (*it)->data == p ){
    (*it)->ageData();
    break;
      }
    }
  }

public:
  template<typename... ARGS>
  HandlePtr create(const ARGS&... args){ 
    HandlePtr h{std::make_shared<Handle>(this, args...)};
    to_add.push_back(h);
    return h;
  }

  void refresh(){
    for(auto it  = items.begin(); it != items.end();){
      if((*it)->data->isDead()){
    delete (*it)->data;
    (*it)->data = nullptr;
    (*it)->ptr = nullptr;
    it = items.erase(it);
      }
      else
    it++;
    }
    for(auto it : to_add){
      items.push_back(it);
    }
  }
};

int main(){
  MemoryManager<Entity> mgr;
  auto e = mgr.create("Hello world!");
  mgr.refresh();
  (*e)->print(); // "Hello world! 0"
  (*e)->print(); // "Hello world! 1"
  (*e)->suicide();
  // The object is still valid, we have not called refresh() yet to destroy it.
  (*e)->print(); // "Hello world! 2"

  mgr.refresh();
  (*e)->print(); // Expected sig fault as object has been removed
  return 0;
}
```